# Install CI gitlab with Docker in Windows

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Trying to install a gitlab runner on my windows machine inside a docker container
Using 
    docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \ -v ${PWD}/gitla
        /gitlab-runner \ -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest

I'm following the official docs but nothing refers to windows
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html

What's the correct way to set-up a docker container to execute a gitlab runner?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no question in this question.

Comment: edited, thanks for the feedback @OlegSklyar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It currently isn't *fully* supported, however there is an [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2609) and relevant [open merge request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/merge_requests/706) to add that functionality!